# Financial mathematics 2

Tags: sequences-and-series, finance

I've been given the following information:

> MR bob borrows 50000 now and promises to repay it in monthly
>   installments over the next eight years. Interest is compounded monthly
>   at 18% per year. He only starts to repay the loan at the end of the
>   sixth month.

Question:

> His last payment of y, if his monthly payment of 1450 is only paid at
>   the end of the first year and he stops these payments at the end of
>   the sixth year. He redeems the loan at the end of the eighth year with
>   a one-off payment of y.

I've come up with the following equation, yet it does not seems to be right.

[image]

Comment: "His last payment of y, is his monthly payment of 1450 is only paid at the end of the first year" What does this mean?

Comment: Edited, sorry, should of been "His last payment of y, if his monthly payment of 1450 is only paid at the end of the first year".

Comment: I don't understand this either: "his monthly payment of 1450 is only paid at the end of the first year and he stops these payments at the end of the sixth year." Is he making a yearly payment equivalent to 1450  monthly every year for 6 years?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.